# Can't tab into an image map area

Tags: jquery, html, css, accessibility, imagemap

I want to add accessibility to this image map so in addition (or instead of) hovering they can tab through the page and the area shape will become focused to reveal the text. (I know it's using a mouseover right now, I'm just trying to fix the focus problem first).

Here's an example of what I am trying to use:

```
<img src=img.png align='center' alt='some text' height='480px' width='1000px'
usemap='#imagemap'>

<map name = 'imagemap'>

<area shape='rect' style='position:relative' id=upperLeft coords='22,70,245,190'
tabIndex='0' alt='alt upper left text' onMouseOver=addUpperLeftText(this);></map>
<span id='upper_left'></span>

function addUpperLeftText(e){
    var upper_left_text = 'Upper left text';
    var cssObj = {
            'position': 'absolute',
            'width': '180px',
            'top': '155px',
            'left': '55px',
            'font-size': '18px',
            'line-height': '20px'
    };
    $('<p>').appendTo('#upper_left').text(upper_left_text).css(cssObj);
    e.onmouseover = null;
}
```

I've tried adding tabindex and an empty href, and my searching for other solutions have come up short. I just want to have the area shape become focused when one tabs through the page.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: that's not adding accessibility to anything. fyi. in fact, not using an image map would be your best bet

Comment: You're right @albert but I was trying to adapt what I already had. After applying the fix suggested below I modified it so it was no longer an image map.

Comment: i felt like a dick after saying that without giving any info....thanks for not taking it like that. my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with absolute positioned anchor elements, doesn't even require jQuery

[demo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j8S97/2/)

```
<div class="imgContainer">
    <img src="//placehold.it/1000x480" align="center" alt="some text" height="480" width="1000" />
    <a id="hotspot1" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
    <a id="hotspot2" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
    <a id="hotspot3" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
</div>
```

```
.imgContainer {
    position:relative;
    width:1000px;
    height:480px;
}

.imgContainer a {
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid #eee;
}

.imgContainer a:focus, .imgContainer a:hover {
    background:rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
}

#hotspot1 {
    top:20px;
    left:77px;
}

#hotspot2 {
    top:180px;
    left:320px;
}

#hotspot3 {
    top:200px;
    left:177px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't think it was jquery but how I was handling the image map. I replaced the <area> tags with <span> and after implementing your suggestions it worked out.

Answer (score 3):

Tabbing through an imagemap seems to work just fine for me:

```
<a href="#">Clickable element</a><br />
<img src="http://engagetolearn.com/ETL/virtualzoo/map.gif" usemap="#my-map" />
<map name="my-map">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,100,100" href="#" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="100,0,200,100" href="#" />
</map>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/YUvZU/

(Make sure to put focus on the jsFiddle output window before tabbing.)